# a:first-child modifying all links within my list

Tags: css

I'm having a problem with my links and I can't seem to find why first-child is acting this way.

Instead of modifying the first link inside my unordered list, it modifies them all. The same thing happens when i try using last-child or nth-child.

Could anyone help me figure this out? Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {margin:0;padding:0;font-size:13px;color:white;font-family:arial;}
        body {background-color:black;}
        #wrapper {margin:0px auto;width:1024px;}

        #types {position:relative;top:4px;width:810px;list-style-type:none;}
        #types li {display:inline;}
        #types a {text-decoration:none;padding:8px;margin:-1px;background-color:#1A1A1A;}
        #types a:hover {background-color:#A02723;}
                #types a:first-child {background-color:#A02723;}

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <ul id="types">
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">9</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to set the first-child of li then it works #types li:first-child a{background-color:#A02723;}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`a:first-child` matches `<a>` elements that are the first child of their parent. Your `<a>` elements are in completely different `<li>`s, so they *all* are the first children of their parent element.

You should match the `<li>` elements instead:

```
#types li:first-child a {background-color:#A02723;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
#types li:first-child a
```

insted.

Comment: I just wrote the selector, obviously you have to add the attributes.