# I can't seem to get css first_child to work

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Normally, this is an incredibly easy task. For some reason, today, it seems to not want to work. Is there something I'm doing wrong? I'm probably sound insanely silly asking this question. :)

Here's the css code:

```
#header > .navigation {
    display: inline-block;
}
    #header > .navigation > a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #202020;
    }
        #header > .navigation > a:first_child { /* This is what isn't working */
            color: #ff0000;
        }
```

Here's the html code:

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="navigation">
        <a href="#">Start</a>
        <a href="#">Account</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <a href="#">Whoah, what is this place?</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a problem with the .navigation being displayed as an inline-block? It's necessary that it keeps a similar display mode, as there is another div next to it inside the #header. I'm not showing this div in the code above to make this message as simple to understand as possible.

Comment: It's first-child with a dash, not an underscore.

Comment: Yes, I thank everybody for helping me resolve my silly mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
#header > .navigation > a:first_child
```

Use:

```
#header > .navigation > a:first-child
```

Comment: is there a difference?

Comment: Yes. first-child instead of _

Answer (score 2):

Error Solved

```
a:first-child{ ... }
```

Matches `<a>` elements that are the first child of their parent. Your  elements are in completely different `<li>`-elements, so they all are the first children of their parent element.

Refer :
[a:first-child modifying all links within my list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420551/afirst-child-modifying-all-links-within-my-list)

Comment: This answer looks strange. "Error Solved" is just about the only text that is relevant to the question even though it looks so out-of-place. The rest of the text that is taken from the link does not apply here at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try it now

Here's the css code:

```
#header > .navigation { display: inline-block; }
#header > .navigation > a { text-decoration: none; color: #202020; }     
#header > .navigation > a:first-child { /* dash not underscore */ color: #ff0000; }
```

Comment: Looks like you over analysed this @foru